# Roots of unity with equation.

Tags: complex-numbers

> $z+\frac{1}{z}=2\cos{3^\circ}$
>
> Find $z^{2000}+\frac{1}{z^{2000}}$

I'm pretty sure it has to to do with roots of unity, but the $2\cos{3^\circ}$ is throwing me off. Some work:
$$z+\frac{1}{z}=2\cos{3^\circ}$$
$$\implies z^2-(2\cos{3^\circ})z+1=0$$
If the "$2\cos{3^\circ}$" term was changed to, we could say $z$ is the complex root of $z^3=1$ and then apply roots of unity. I'm also conjecturing $z^n$ repeats every 3.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use chebyshev polynomials. Answer is $-1$[image]

Comment: you should rotate the image

Comment: @Manx Indeed, but better still, not use an image.

Answer (score 2):

If you have $z+1/z=2\cos t$, then $z=e^{it}$ or $e^{-it}$. In either case, $z^n+1/z^n=e^{int}+e^{-int}=2\cos nt$.